# Переименновать сетевые диски

Tags: администрирование, файловая-система

Предстоит задача переноса данных с одного сетевого пути *\\server1\* на *\\server2\*.

У пользователей в сети настроены сетевые диски, которые ведут в различные папки на server1. Если мы просто скопируем папки с одного сервера на другой, то все диски перестанут работать. Ходить до каждого компьютера и менять пути - муторно и долго.

Вопрос: можно ли как-либо, посредством управления политикой/скриптами, поменять на всех компьютерах в сети путь сетевого диска?

Например: *\\server1\folder1*, *\\server1\folder2* меняем на *\\server2\folder1*, *\\server2\folder2*

Comment: Напишите VBS-скрипт, который пробежит по всем подразделам в `HKCU\Network`, и во всех (или некоторых - можно захардкодить) `RemotePath` поменяет `\\server1\` на `\\server2\`. И пихните его в политику. При очередном входе все пути перепишутся.

Comment: А вообще в домене должен быть хотя бы один сервер с ролью файлового сервера. Все шары отправить на него, и при необходимости корректировать пути именно там. И подключаться именно через шары этого сервера - ресурс физически не обязан находиться там, где расположены сведения о нём.

Comment: Так а до этого диски аттачились не через gpo?